# Trying to understand the use of pointers in a function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm just trying to understand this function. Am I right in saying the return type is a pointer to an object Fruit and that should be an address in memory? Also I'm returning the dereferenced object of Fruit in fruitInCharacter which is also a memory address?

```
Fruit* Player::fruit(int location)
{
    if (location<(int)fruitInCharacter.size()) {
        return &fruitInCharacter.at(location);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Also in the second function I am passing in a pointer (address in memory) into the vector using .push back?

```
void Player::attachFruit(Fruit *inFruit)
{
  fruitInCharacter.push_back(*inFruit);

}
```

Comment: `*inFruit` is not a pointer, but the object pointed by the pointer.

Comment: Yes you are right. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know specifically what you're trying to do and if it's correct, we would need to see the declaration of the `vector` `fruitInCharacter`. Since you're not mentioning any compiler errors, I'm deducing that it's `std::vector<Fruit>`.

```
Fruit* Player::fruit(int location)
{
    if (location<(int)fruitInCharacter.size()) {
        return &fruitInCharacter.at(location);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

> Am I right in saying the return type is a pointer to an object Fruit and that should be an address in memory?

**Yes**.

> Also I'm returning the dereferenced object of Fruit in fruitInCharacter which is also a memory address?

**No**. You're returning the address of an object of Fruit in `fruitInCharacter`. If `fruitInCharacter` is of type `std::vector<Fruit>` then this is correct. If it is of type `std::vector<Fruit*>`, then it isn't, and shouldn't compile.

```
void Player::attachFruit(Fruit *inFruit)
{
  fruitInCharacter.push_back(*inFruit);

}
```

> Also in the second function I am passing in a pointer (address in memory) into the vector using .push back?

**No**. You're passing a pointer into the method, but you are dereferencing the pointer, causing a *copy* of the object that `inFruit` points to to be stored in the vector. If the vector stores elements of type `Fruit`, that's correct but not doing what you think it does. If it stores elements of type `Fruit*` then it shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** The return type is a pointer to a `Fruit` object, and that "should be" an address in memory.

**No.** You are not returning "the dereferenced object of `Fruit` in `fruitInCharacter`, which is also a memory address". You are returning the *address* of a `Fruit` object which is inside `fruitInCharacter`. You are using the `&` operator, so you are taking the *address* of that object.

**No.** In the second function you are not "passing in a pointer (address in memory) into the vector". You are passing an object. Since `inFruit` is of type `Fruit *` (hence, it is an address), the dereferenced expression `*inFruit` is of type `Fruit` (hence, it is an object).

Answer (score 0):

&fruitInCharacter.at(location); It's not dereferenced.
fruitInCharacter.at(location) will give you a Fruit& type object.
However your return type is a pointer, so you get the ptr to it with the & operator.

fruitInCharacter.push_back(*inFruit): Here you dereference the Fruit* type variable, so it will pass a Fruit (const Fruit& actually), and your container will make a COPY from it.